# Acumatica tooltip postion

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, acumatica

I have a code:

```
 <div>
     <px:PXImage runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Icons/info.png" Enabled="False" Height="16" Width="16"
                                             ToolTip="Excludes current pay amount." />
 </div>
```

That looks like this on the screen:

[image]

As you can see the tool time hid another UI element. Moreover, my requirements wants the tooltip to appear on the right like this:

[image]

Is that possible to change the location of the tooltip in Acumatica framework (like on the screenshot with yellow UI element on the right from the round icon)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at cascading style sheets, but this is a function of the Cascading Style Sheet used by the Theme within Acumatica.  Fortunately, making your own version of the theme is pretty straightforward.  I know this answer doesn't get you completely to the finish line, but hopefully someone will be able to build on it to get the exact changes needed to position the tooltip.  I did manage to recreate a sample of the arrow and box color changes, including removal of the blue arrow that Acumatica's standard theme uses.

1. Navigate to the base folder for the website and go into the
   **App_Themes** folder.
2. Copy the **Default** folder to the same **App_Themes** folder and give it a new name for your custom theme.
3. Navigate back to the base folder for the website and go into the **Content** folder.
4. Copy the Site.css file to Site[custom theme name].css (in my case, my theme is Brian so my css file will be SiteBrian.css.
5. Edit your custom theme css file.
6. Navigate back to the **App_Themes[Custom Theme Name]** folder and open the 00_Controls.css stylesheet.
7. Locate the section for **#tooltip** (Referenced in the file as Tooltip Css classes) and apply your edits.
8. In Acumatica, navigate to Site Preferences, and select your custom theme.  When you save it and refresh the page where you are testing your tooltip changes, you should see the tooltips adjust accordingly.

Unfortunately, figuring out how to adjust the placement of the tooltip div so that it is where you want it beside the object is not something I was able to determine.  However, this is what I came up with to get the look of the tooltip (for errors) if you can figure out the placement.  [image]

In 00_Controls.css:

```
/*------------------ Tooltip Css classes ------------------ */
#tooltip {
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #007ACC;
  background-color: var(--primary-color, #007ACC);
  border: 1px solid #007ACC;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color, #007ACC);
  color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 80px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%;
}

#tooltip a {
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-size: 11px;
  float: right;
}

#tooltip .arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  bottom: -16px;
}

#tooltip .arrow.top {
  top: -16px;
  bottom: auto;
}

#tooltip .arrow.left {
  left: 20%;
}

/* Comment this out to remove the blue arrow Acumatica uses
#tooltip .arrow:after {
  background-color: #007ACC;
  background-color: var(--primary-color, #007ACC);
  border: 1px solid #007ACC;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color, #007ACC);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: -200px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
*/

#tooltip .arrow.top:after {
  bottom: -20px;
  top: auto;
}

#tooltip.error, .arrow:after {
  background-color: RGBA(230, 197, 67, 0.87);
  border-color: RGBA(230, 197, 67, 0.87);
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#tooltip.error::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%; /* To the left of the tooltip */
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent RGBA(230, 197, 67, 0.87) transparent transparent;
}

#tooltip.warn, #tooltip.warn .arrow:after {
  background-color: #ffeb3b;
  border-color: Brown;
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

I'm interested in the changes required in the stylesheet if you figure out how to set the position to be to the right.

Comment: Hi, Brian,
Looks like the tooltip still hiding the UI element below. This was initial problem when tooltip hides another element and we wanted to put the tooltip on the right side of the menu. there is the "pencil" icon in your example. Probably, needs to "play" with CSS style. But is it possible to apply it on the target page only to avoid overriding of whole tooltips?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you in not figuring that part out.  The example I found to put it on the right in my research is quite easy in a stylesheet as a SPAN for the tooltip nested in the DIV.  However, it looks like the tooltip is its own DIV.  While I know you can overlay DIV's on top of each other, those settings are beyond me.  I did spend a couple of hours trying to get you an answer, but I just couldn't commit any additional time, so I provided what I could.  I'm really interested in the solution if you find it.  In the meantime, I learned to use a custom CSS to make my own tweaks!

Comment: I have pretty limited knowledge in the web front-end, but my company works close with Aucmatica developers in Moscow, and I will ask about that next time we communicate and will provide the answer if it exists. Thank you for your time and efforts, Brian.